# Scala Compiler Cannot Apply Installation for Project Settings

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide

I am working on eclipse for last one year. Now I faced an issue in using scala project settings instead of default. Eclipse cannot apply the scala installation.

I attached Screen shot in which my project required scala installation is selected but apply and close button is not working on any type of scala installation.
If anyone can help me?
[image: Eclipse IDE]